# Why can't I run my code in a browser or JS Fiddle?

Tags: javascript, html

With full disclosure, I am brand new to JS.  I don't fully comprehend the nature of the language (e.g. is it written in html, what is the difference between JS and html?).  So needless to say, I am a novice.  That being said, I'm trying to build an experiment in jspsych and I went through the tutorials, tried to run the sample code, and got "Invalid JavaScript Code."  I cannot find any answers to why this is.  It neither works in a browser or on JS Fiddle's testing software.  I would appreciate any help with this.

P.S. I'm a decent programmer in Python, and the JS syntax seems pretty straight forward, but I'm out to sea when it comes to formatting, etc.

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>My experiment</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jspsych-5.0.3/jspsych.js"></script>
        <script src="jspsych-5.0.3/plugins/jspsych-text.js"></script>
        <script src="jspsych-5.0.3/plugins/jspysch-single-stim.js"></script>
        <link href="jspsych-5.0.3/css/jspsych.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <script>

    /* define welcome message block */
    var welcome_block = {
        type: "text"
        text: "Welcome to the experiment. Press any key to begin."
    };

    /*define instructions block*/
    var instructions_block = {
        type:"text",
        text:"<p>In this experiment,a circle will appear in the center" +
            "of the screen.</p><p>If the circle is <strong>blue</strong>," +
            "press the letter F on the keyboard as fast as you can.</p>" +
            "<p>If the circle is <strong>orange</strong>, do not press " +
            "any key.</p>"+
            "<div class ='left center-conten'><img src='img/blue.png'></img>" +
            "<p class = 'small'><strong>Press the F key</strong></p></div>" +
            "div class='right center-content'><img src='img/orang.png'></img>" +
            "<p class='small'><strong>Do not press a key</strong></p></div>" +
            "<p>Press any key to begin.</p>"
        timing_post_trial: 2000     
    };

    var test_stimuli = [
        {
            stimulus: 'img/blue.png',
            data: { response: 'go'}
        },
        {
            stimulus: 'img/orange.png',
            data: { response: 'no-go'}
        }
    ];

    var all_trials = jsPsych.randomization.repeat(test_stimuli,10);


    var post_trial_gap = function() {
        return Math.floor( math.random() * 1500) + 750;
    }

    var test_block = {
        type: 'single-stim',
        choices: ['F'],
        timing_response: 1500,
        timing_post_trial: post_trial_gap,
        on_finish: function(data){
            var correct = false;
            if(data.response == 'go' && data.rt > -1){
                correct = true;
            } else if(data.response == 'no-go' && data.rt == -1){
                correct = true;
            }
            jsPsych.data.addDataToLastTrial({correct: correct});
        },            
        timeline: all_trials
    };

/*define debrief block*/
    function getSubjectData() {

        var trials = jsPsych.data.getTrialsofType('single-stim');

        var sum_rt = 0;
        var correct_trial_count = 0;
        var correct_rt_count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < trials.length; i++) {
            if (trials[i].correct == true) {
                correct_trial_count++;
                if(trials[i].rt > -1){
                    sum_rt += trials[i].rt;
                    correct_rt_count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return {
            rt: Math.floor(sum_rt/correct_rt_count),
            accuracy: Math.floor(correct_trial_count / trials.length * 100)
        }
    }

    var debrief_block = {
        type: "text",
        text: function() {
            var subject_data = getSubjectData();
            return"<p>You responded correctly on "+subject_data.accuracy+"% of "+
            "the trials.</p><p>Your average response time was <strong>"+
            subject_data.rt + "ms</strong>.  Press any key to complete the "+
            "experiment. Thank you!</p>";
        }
    };

    /*create experiment timeline array*/
    var timeline = [];
    timeline.push(welcome_block);
    timeline.push(instructions_block);
    timeline.push(test_block);
    timeline.pysh(debrief_block)

    /*start the experiment*/
    jsPsych.init({ 
        experiment_structure: experiment,
        on_finish: function() {
            jsPsych.data.displayData();
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Open the browser's JavaScript console. Look at the error messages there.

Comment: At first sight, I see missing commas in your Objects. They should look like this: `var myObj = {type: "x", text: "y"};`

Comment: `welcome_block` and `instructions_block` are missing commas between some key/value pairs.

Comment: Your objects are missing commas. The JavaScript console should point you to the errors

Comment: JavaScript is a separate programming language, defined independently of web browsers and HTML. It just so happens that JavaScript was chosen as the scripting language of choice for browsers. It can also be a server-side language using Node.js

Comment: @4castle OP is new to JS and doesn't quite understand it, bringing Node to the mix will make their head explode.

Comment: @CarlMarkham I'm just making a point that JavaScript can be used independently of a browser. I'm not saying they need to go learn how it's done.

Comment: I've since updated the code with commas, etc.  And in JS Fiddle I'm getting no syntactic errors, yet when I run the program it says "Invalid JS."

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the code posted here on SO? It looks like you still have some missing commas as I have indicated here with "//<-- YOU NEED A COMMA HERE". See below:

```
    var welcome_block = {
        type: "text", //<-- YOU NEED A COMMA HERE
        text: "Welcome to the experiment. Press any key to begin."
    };

    /*define instructions block*/
    var instructions_block = {
        type:"text",
        text:"<p>In this experiment,a circle will appear in the center" +
        "of the screen.</p><p>If the circle is <strong>blue</strong>," +
        "press the letter F on the keyboard as fast as you can.</p>" +
        "<p>If the circle is <strong>orange</strong>, do not press " +
        "any key.</p>"+
        "<div class ='left center-conten'><img src='img/blue.png'></img>" +
        "<p class = 'small'><strong>Press the F key</strong></p></div>" +
        "div class='right center-content'><img src='img/orang.png'></img>" +
        "<p class='small'><strong>Do not press a key</strong></p></div>" +
        "<p>Press any key to begin.</p>", //<-- YOU NEED A COMMA HERE
        timing_post_trial: 2000
    };
```

EDIT: Another typo (math.random() should be Math.random());

```
 var post_trial_gap = function() {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * 1500) + 750;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've made all of the necessary syntactic edits.

Comment: Now the text for the experiment is appearing on my browser, but it's not actually running it.

Comment: You also has not capitalized Math.random(). Did you already fix that? FYI - Its hard for anyone to help you if we aren't seeing the code as it currently is in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code:

```
/* define welcome message block */
var welcome_block = {
    type: "text",
    text: "Welcome to the experiment. Press any key to begin."
};

/* define instructions block */
var instructions_block = {
    type: "text",
    text: "<p>In this experiment, a circle will appear in the center " +
        "of the screen.</p><p>If the circle is <strong>blue</strong>, " +
        "press the letter F on the keyboard as fast as you can.</p>" +
        "<p>If the circle is <strong>orange</strong>, do not press " +
        "any key.</p>" +
        "<div class='left center-content'><img src='img/blue.png'></img>" +
        "<p class='small'><strong>Press the F key</strong></p></div>" +
        "<div class='right center-content'><img src='img/orange.png'></img>" +
        "<p class='small'><strong>Do not press a key</strong></p></div>" +
        "<p>Press any key to begin.</p>",
    timing_post_trial: 2000
};

/* define test block */

var test_stimuli = [
    {
    stimulus: "img/blue.png",
    data: { response: 'go' }
    },
    {
    stimulus: "img/orange.png",
    data: { response: 'no-go' }
    }
];

var all_trials = jsPsych.randomization.repeat(test_stimuli, 10);

var post_trial_gap = function() {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * 1500 ) + 750;
}

var test_block = {
    type: "single-stim",
    choices: ['F'],
    timing_response: 1500,
    timing_post_trial: post_trial_gap,
    on_finish: function(data){
    var correct = false;
    if(data.response == 'go' && data.rt > -1){
        correct = true;
    } else if(data.response == 'no-go' && data.rt == -1){
        correct = true;
    }
    jsPsych.data.addDataToLastTrial({correct: correct});
    },
    timeline: all_trials
    };

    /* define debrief block */

function getSubjectData() {

    var trials = jsPsych.data.getTrialsOfType('single-stim');

    var sum_rt = 0;
    var correct_trial_count = 0;
    var correct_rt_count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < trials.length; i++) {
    if (trials[i].correct == true) {
        correct_trial_count++;
        if(trials[i].rt > -1){
        sum_rt += trials[i].rt;
        correct_rt_count++;
        }
    }
    }
    return {
    rt: Math.floor(sum_rt / correct_rt_count),
    accuracy: Math.floor(correct_trial_count / trials.length * 100)
    }
}

    var debrief_block = {
    type: "text",
    text: function() {
        var subject_data = getSubjectData();
        return "<p>You responded correctly on "+subject_data.accuracy+"% of "+
        "the trials.</p><p>Your average response time was <strong>" +
        subject_data.rt + "ms</strong>. Press any key to complete the "+
        "experiment. Thank you!</p>";
    }
    };

    /* create experiment timeline array */
    var timeline = [];
    timeline.push(welcome_block);
    timeline.push(instructions_block);
    timeline.push(test_block);
    timeline.push(debrief_block);

    /* start the experiment */
    jsPsych.init({
    timeline: timeline,
    on_finish: function() {
        jsPsych.data.displayData();
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

After fetching the library and creating a blue and orange png I ran the experiment with the following correction to your last code post.  The plugin name you have is incorrect.  By the way, my time was 303ms.

```
<script src="jspsych-5.0.3/plugins/jspsych-single-stim.js"></script>
```